# db2: jdbc preparestatement not work for fetch ? rows only

Tags: jdbc, db2

I'm using db2 driver 11.5.8.0. DB2 9.7
And when I try to fetch rows, it throws error.

```
SqlSyntaxExceptionError: SLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601, SQLERRMC=?;om tuser fetch first;<space>, DRIVER=4.32.28
```

My code is like this

```
  val ps = connection.prepareStatement("select * from tuser fetch first ? rows only")
  ps.setObject(1, 1)
  ps.use {
    val rs = ps.executeQuery()
    // doSomeThing
  }
```

If I not use ? but 1, it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't use a parameter marker for the "fetch first N rows" clause.
Use an alternate approach, for example:

```
SELECT *
FROM 
(
  SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER () OVER () AS RN_
  FROM tuser
) T
WHERE T.RN_ <= ?
```

Comment: I know this, but I'm try to write dialect  for orm. I need implment limit.

Comment: What does it mean: "to write dialect for orm"?

Comment: OK.I want use kommaper(an orm), it didn't support db2, so I decide to write its db2 dialect myself. if I can't do like this. so there is no way unless the orm core changes.Am I right?

Comment: Again, Db2 doesn't support parameter markers in the FFNR clause. If this means, that you have to do orm core changes, then yes, you have to do it.